# I accidentally deleted the saved pictures album

Tags: onedrive, photos, backup, nokia-lumia-820

I deleted saved picture album by mistake from my Lumia 820. Can I return it back with Zune app or something other ways? Btw I didn't activate the OneDrive service before deleting the album.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't back up your photos in any way (through Zune or OneDrive for example) there is not really a way to recover those without opening up the device, getting the memory chip, rendering your warranty void and propably damaging the phone. Sorry.

Comment: So, there is no other way :( Does anyone else got any idea?